# How to use applicationId outside defaultConfig in gradle?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

This is possibly a silly quiestion, but I want to have a debug and release versions of app working at the same time on device.

The problem I had is a content resolver authority. So I did the usual applicationId jazz, but now i want to avoid having code like this

```
public static final String AUTHORITY = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider";
```

laying around, so I figured I would do a BuildConfigField for CONTENT_AUTHORITY which would do the concat in buildfile already like this

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        BuildConfigField "String", "CONTENT_AUTHORITY", "\"${applicationId}.provider\"")
    }
    release {
        ....
    }
}
```

**But it doesnt work**, gradle/groovy syntax is confusing for me, help please?

> Error:(32, 0) Could not find property 'applicationId' on
>   BuildType_Decorated{name=debug, debuggable=true,
>   testCoverageEnabled=false, jniDebuggable=false,
>   pseudoLocalesEnabled=false, renderscriptDebuggable=false,
>   renderscriptOptimLevel=3, applicationIdSuffix=.debug,
>   versionNameSuffix=null, minifyEnabled=false, zipAlignEnabled=true,...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try accessing it as

```
defaultConfig.applicationId
```

Instead of just

```
applicationId
```

Should get you the value.